# Find the curl if the vector field depends on a parameter

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, differentiation, vector-fields, conservative-field

Given the following vector,
\begin{align}
    F(x(t),y(t),z(t)) &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \omega_1^2 x_o\cos(\omega_1 t) \\
           \omega_2y_0\sin(\omega_2 t)\\
           0\\
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

I want to determine the curl: $\nabla \times F. $ Even though it should be easy, I could not come along. The first problem is, I do not get if coordinates used can be considered as polar or cylindrical. I think they can't be either, since the angle function is different for $\cos$ and $\sin$. But it is difficult to consider them as cartesian coordinates as well, so that I do not see how to calculate the curl. I want to prove or reject that $F$ is conservative. Instead of finding a potential and prove that the gradient of that function is equal to the given force, I wanted to rather try to find the curl of the function $F.$ Can somebody provide some insight or a solution proposal?  Thanks.

Comment: The vector field is time dependent and so it cannot be conservative.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do that analytically by proving that the curl is not vanishing ?

Comment: I might be missing something but the components of $F$ are homogeneous in space. At fixed $t$ the vector $F$ is constant. Since the curl only involves derivatives with respect to space coordinates, shouldn't the curl be strictly zero?

Comment: Related [Force and energy relation: in case of time dependent force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256420/force-and-energy-relation-in-case-of-time-dependent-force)