# Is a velocity-dependent force $\vec{F}$ that doesn't do any work on an object a conservative force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, velocity, conservative-field

Let's consider a point like object with mass $m$ upon which acts a force $\vec{F} = \vec{c} \times \vec{v}$  ($\vec{c}$ is supposed to be a constant vector). Given that $\vec{F}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{v}$ and therefore to $\vec{r}$, the work $W$ done by $\vec{F}$ should be zero.
So if $W$ is always zero, then $\oint \vec{F}d\vec{r} = 0$ and $\vec{F}$ should be a [conservative force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force), right? And if $\vec{F}$ is conservative, then we have conservation of energy.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/528336/2451 and links therein.

Comment: $\vec F$ perpendicular to $\vec v$ does not necessarily mean $\vec F$ is perpendicular to $\vec r$.  Look at uniform circular motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a measure of freedom in the way you define a conservative force, but the usual definition is that the vector can be written as a gradient, in other words you can define a scalar field that depends on position only so that:
$$\vec{F}=-\vec{\nabla}V$$
Within this definition, a force perpendicular to velocity can be non-conservative.

A force with an expression like the one you mention is the magnetic part of the Lorentz force:
$$\vec{F}=q\vec{V}\times\vec{B}$$
But think about forces like the tension of the string for a pendulum, or the reaction of the ground on an object. Those forces don't work, but I really wouldn't consider them conservative.