# If a force depends on velocity, then why is the force not conservative? I need a formal proof

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, velocity, conservative-field

I am currently an undergraduate taking a course on Newtonian mechanics. The lecturer defines a force to be conservative if there exists a scalar function (we call it potential function), say $V(x,y,z)$, such that the force $$\mathbf{F}=-\Big(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\mathbf{\hat i}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\mathbf{\hat j}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}\mathbf{\hat k}\Big).$$ Then the lecturer told us that whenever you see an expression of $\mathbf{F}$ which depends on velocity $\mathbf{v}$, then this force must be non-conservative. Then I asked why, because I think in some scenario $\mathbf{v}$ can be expressed solely in terms of an object's position vector $\mathbf{r}$, but the response was not clear. Could anyone comment on the lecturer's statement and explain why?

I know there are similar questions on this community, but I has not found a rigorous proof to, say, how to show that $\mathbf{F}=A\mathbf{v}$, where $A$ is a non-zero constant, is not conservative? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't conservative forces depend on velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/528336/)

Comment: There are many more questions here. Please use the search function, click on related links etc.

Comment: You should point out where all other threads have not addressed your query. I don't see that this is the case, tbh. Also, how do you define conservative, to start with? If you want a proof, you have to state precise definitions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why can't we ascribe a (possibly velocity dependent) potential to a dissipative force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20929/2451)

Comment: If the force depends on the velocity, it is not a function of $x$ alone. It is rather a function(al) of a trajectory: $t\to x(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

A force is not conservative if work depends on the path taken by the particles.
Work is defined as

$$W = \int_A^B \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

Now you see that if $\vec{F}$ depends on the velocity $\vec{v}$, you will not have the same integral for $W$ depending on the path you take.

You are stating that $\vec{v}$ can depend solely on $\vec{r}$. This is true, but the changes in velocity $\vec{v}$ of the particle moving along the path $A\to B$ is generated by the forces acting on it, such that it must be obtained from solving the equations of motions.
For forces dependent in $\vec{v}$ it is thus impossible to express the velocity solely in term of $\vec{r}$ by solving the second law of dynamics ($m\dot{\vec{v}}=\vec{F}(\vec{v})$), such that you can never find a path independent expression for $W$. You can think of simple examples as motion with friction e.g. $\vec{F}=-k\vec{v}$. In that case, you will obtain $|\vec{v}| \propto e^{\frac{k}{m}t}$, such that $W$ will depend on the path (the longer the path, the greater the time $t$ and the greater the work!).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still do not understand. Say $\mathbf{F}=A\mathbf{v}$ where $A$ is a non-zero constant, then how to show with rigor that $\mathbf{F}$ is not conservative?

Comment: So I would say that you can take two approaches. Either you compute explicitly $W$ and you will obtain something like 

$$W = \int_A^B \vec{F}\cdot d \vec{\ell} =   \int_A^B A \vec{v}\cdot d \vec{\ell} \propto   \int_A^B A e^{\frac{k}{m}t} d\ell$$

And here you showed that $W$ is proportional to the time to go from $A$ to $B$, proving that the force is non conservative because it depends on the path.

Otherwise you can try to prove the impossibility to find a $V(x,y,z)$ such that $\vec{F}=-\vec{\nabla}V$. For sure examples of this can be found in textbooks.

Comment: If you want I can try to sketch (or find) a proof of the second type.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I realize that I am lack of some knowledge of vector calculus, for which I only know some rules of differentiating dot and cross products, in order to understand your response. So, I am leaving this question for now, but I'll come back to it later.

Comment: Of course no problem! First time in classical mechanics is always hard. Let me know if I can help later.

Comment: You are so kind. Thank you! I will start learning about vector calculus in two weeks. Hopefully, at the end of March, I would be able to understand your response.